# How to include named parameters in F# documentation

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'd like to include documentation with my `F#` functions.  As a new user, I recently discovered the XML tags built into `F#`; that information for those tags [can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233217.aspx).

My problem is that the `param` tags don't seem to do anything in the mouse-over window that pops up.  For example, this function, with simple XML tags:

```
//A simple function for StackOverflow question
/// <summary> A test function to post to StackOverflow that doesn't do much at all.</summary>
/// <param name=" x "> A string to pass to the function.</param>
let printString (x: string) = 
    printfn "This is what you input into the function: %s" x
```

produces this mouse-over:

[image]

I would have expected the parameter `x` to have been defined in this mouse-over pop-up.  Is the tag incorrect?  If so, what does the tag need to be for the parameter names to be included in the intellisense pop-up?

Thanks for your comments and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag is correct, but for whatever reason, these popups just don't list the parameters. For what it's worth, this works the same way in C#.

You can, however, get it to work like it does in C# if you start typing your invocation in C# style:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm thinking I was confusing the mouse-over pop ups with the invocation pop-ups.